# Unzip then process in linux

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a script which unzips a file:

```
#!/bin/bash -e 
# will unzip the data without removing the zipped version
gzip -dc $1 > RawData/unzipped/$(basename $1 .gz)
```

I then want to execute code on that unzipped file, I have

```
# will run fast qc on the argument passed
fastqc RawData/unzipped/$(basename $1 .gz) --outdir=fastReports/
```

but the second script never seems to execute. (Note these are in the same script so I was assuming it would execute the initial script before the second one)

Zipped:

```
14624_1#10_1.fastq.gz  14624_1#12_2.fastq.gz  14624_1#4_1.fastq.gz  14624_1#7_1.fastq.gz
14624_1#10_2.fastq.gz  14624_1#1_2.fastq.gz   14624_1#4_2.fastq.gz  14624_1#7_2.fastq.gz
14624_1#11_1.fastq.gz  14624_1#2_1.fastq.gz   14624_1#5_1.fastq.gz  14624_1#8_1.fastq.gz
14624_1#11_2.fastq.gz  14624_1#2_2.fastq.gz   14624_1#5_2.fastq.gz  14624_1#8_2.fastq.gz
14624_1#1_1.fastq.gz   14624_1#3_1.fastq.gz   14624_1#6_1.fastq.gz  14624_1#9_1.fastq.gz
14624_1#12_1.fastq.gz  14624_1#3_2.fastq.gz   14624_1#6_2.fastq.gz  14624_1#9_2.fastq.gz
```

Extracted:

```
14624_1#10_1.fastq  14624_1#12_1.fastq  14624_1#3_1.fastq  14624_1#5_2.fastq  14624_1#8_1.fastq
14624_1#10_2.fastq  14624_1#12_2.fastq  14624_1#3_2.fastq  14624_1#6_1.fastq  14624_1#8_2.fastq
14624_1#11_1.fastq  14624_1#1_2.fastq   14624_1#4_1.fastq  14624_1#6_2.fastq  14624_1#9_1.fastq
14624_1#11_2.fastq  14624_1#2_1.fastq   14624_1#4_2.fastq  14624_1#7_1.fastq  14624_1#9_2.fastq
14624_1#1_1.fastq   14624_1#2_2.fastq   14624_1#5_1.fastq  14624_1#7_2.fastq
```

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: Sorry I thought I explained it: It is unzipping the files, but it is not then processing the data, so it's not running fastqc. I have checked its not a problem with fastqc as I run that exact script when all of the files have been unzipped and it works perfectly. @Inian

Comment: Is `RawData/unzipped/$(basename $1 .gz)` producing a single file or multiple files?

Comment: a single file @Inian

Comment: Could you post an `ls -l` of your gzipped file and an `ls -l` of the extracted file? With directory names possibly?

Comment: I've added the ls @linuxfan

Comment: I suspect that a hash `#` in the filename could give some trouble, but I am not sure. Making a test using a file -without- hashes could show something.

Comment: yeah its not the # @linuxfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just use `zcat` and process the file on the fly:

```
fastqc <(zcat path/to/file.gz)
```

Btw, the `<()` syntax is a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

If you need both the unzipped file and the process result you may use `tee`:

```
fastqc <(zcat path/to/file.gz | tee file)
```

Comment: I have been looking at process substitution, but the thing is I will also need the unzipped files for other processes so I didn't think this would be the way to go

Comment: Use `tee` for that

Comment: In the end I just used `fastqc $1` as it supports zip ha